# android imageview curtain style animation

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

in an android application, I have an imageview. I want to put another image on top of it. And while the user is touching the image, the top image will slide up like a curtain, to reveal the image below it. When the user removes his finger, I will go to another page

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Basically I know I have to implement the OnTouch Listener and worl on the "ACTION_DOWN" and "ACTION_UP" cases. But what I don't know is how to do that curtain slide up animation? because translation would translate the whole image and not just in the image canvas.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to achieve it by having two `ImageView`s under `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/solid_blue"
        android:id="@+id/img_back"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/solid_green"
        android:id="@+id/img_front"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And in the activity adding onTouchListener and translating the front ImageView would do the job:

```
ObjectAnimator mSlideAnim; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.curtainstyle);

    final ImageView imgFront = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_front);

    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    parent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (mSlideAnim == null) {
                        triggerSlideUpAnimation(imgFront);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    goToAnotherPage();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void triggerSlideUpAnimation(ImageView imgFront) {
    int height = imgFront.getHeight();
    mSlideAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgFront, "translationY", 0, -height);
    mSlideAnim.setDuration(300);
    mSlideAnim.start();
}

private void goToAnotherPage() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Go to another page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: hey @Aziz how can i have this animation on load of fragment and not on ontouch